# Riemann sum total distance, with sign change, seems to be 2 solutions.

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

My question is about finding the total distance traveled, between 0 and 9, given the velocity function defined by the table below, using the trapezoidal approximation with 3 sub-intervals. 
[image: 1]

There seems to be two different logical ways to approach this, that end up with different values.

I know this means we have to find the value of :

$\int_{0}^{9} |v(t)| dt$

and graphically all we know for sure is shown below:
[image: 2]

But there seems to be 2 ways to interpret this, depending on what we assume happens between (4,5) and (6,-6). I will consider the two cases as $v_1(t)$ and $v_2(t)$, and their graphical representations are shown below:
[image: 3]
(notice both function fit the discrete points given in the table)

Algebraically, in the $v_1(t)$ case, we find the trapezoid areas using the negatives, and then take the absolute value. 
$\int_{0}^{9} |v_1(t)| dt \approx  \left|  \frac{1+5}{2} \cdot 4 \right| + \left|  \frac{5+-6}{2} \cdot 2 \right| + \left|  \frac{-6+-4}{2} \cdot 3 \right| =12+1+15=28 $

And, in the $v_2(t)$ case, first we take the absolute value of the table values, and then find the trapezoid areas. 
$\int_{0}^{9} |v_2(t)| dt \approx    \frac{|1|+|5|}{2} \cdot 4  +  \frac{|5|+|-6|}{2} \cdot 2 +   \frac{|-6|+|-4|}{2} \cdot 3  =12+11+15=38 $

Both  ways seem to have merit. Are both answers correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variant $v_1$, while intuitively more exact, does not conform to the task description of using only the 3 given intervals.

And as you found yourself, you can not be sure how the intervals are filled, so both values are in the range of possible values of the "true" integral. But then the other intervals could also be filled with highly accelerated velocity profiles.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand that we have no idea what the "true" integral is, and geometrically $v_1$ appears to be be 2 trapezoids and 2 triangles. So you seem to be implying that $v_2$ is correct. However algebraically, $v_1$ only has 3 parts,  furthermore $\int_{0}^{9} v(t) dt$ calculated with "three" sub-intervals, will geometrically have  2 trapezoids and 2 triangles. So if we think of the two triangles as parts of a single trapezoid then BOTH variants have 3 intervals.

Comment: Yes, for any given value of "correct". $v_1$ uses more of the available information, thus would be the better "guess".